# Does it matter which NetworkView I make an RPC from in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rpc

I've been wondering, if I write
`fxManager.GetComponent<NetworkView>().RPC("bla", bla.bla);`
it works, BUT if I write
`this.GetComponent<NetworkView>().RPC("bla", bla.bla);`
it works perfectly too

Is there even a difference how to call RPCs?
Should I define the exact I want to get the RPC from or can I just call it on desired object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter which you do. Any `NetworkView` can send the RPC.